# How to check if value exists in an array using Velocity Template Language

Tags: java, loops, velocity, vtl, apache-velocity

I am not sure how I could achieve the following using Velocity Template Language.

Essentially, I'd like to check if a given value exists from the given list/array. In C#, it's equivalent to `.Any()` or `.Contains()` method.

```
#set($myValues = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry"])
#foreach($i in $items)
    $myValues.any($i) <= better way to achieve this??
    or something like this
    $myValues.contains($i)
#end
```

Of course, I could just use multiple `if...else...` conditions and loop through the list to check the existence of a certain value, but the code gets messy very quickly (if a lookup list is huge). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `$myValues.contains($i)` should work just fine as velocity can interpret such method calls, as long as they are java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$myValues.contains($i)
```

or

```
$list.contains($myValues, $i)
```

(this one is deprecated since the former was introduced in Velocity 1.6)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Would it be case-sensitive?

Comment: @woodykiddy yes, `"A"` and `"a"` isn't the same in Java if you use `String`'s equals (which will be used by `List#contains`)